# Binding ComboBox by code results in System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I have two ComboBoxes in my Windows Phone 8.1 app:

- one for the Companies (ComboBoxCompany)
- one for the employees of a Company (ComboBoxEmployees)

Suppose their XAML is like this.

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxEmployees"
      SelectionChanged="ComboBoxEmployees_SelectionChanged">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person_Name}"/>                                  
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxCompany"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBoxCompany_SelectionChanged">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company_Name}"/>                                 
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Whenever I change the Company in ComboBoxCompany, it refreshes the list of ComboBox1, assigning and displaying a new list of Employees.

```
private void ComboBoxCompany_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //whenever I select the company name, it must change the employees list on the ComboBoxEmployees
        //let's save it into an ObservableCollection
    ObservableCollection <Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    //...fill employees with data...
    ComboBoxEmployees.ItemsSource = employees; //<-- Debugger breaks right here.
}
```

But when assigning the new `ItemsSource`, **the debugger breaks**. 
I've searched a bit, and it seems I had to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `Employee` class, which I did for every field, but nothing was resolved.
The exception thrown is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

**If I catch it and show it on console, the debugger doesn't stop** and ComboBoxEmployees is filled with data and random errors: sometimes Employees are mismatched or just give `null` pointers.

This is not the first Binding at runtime: when starting the application, ComboBoxCompany is filled with Companies, and ComboBoxEmployees is filled with the employees of the first company: it happens in another method, but the instruction used is the same:

```
public MainPage() {
   InitializeComponent();
   SetPage();
}

private void SetPage(){
   //getting companies data from DB...
   ComboBoxCompany.ItemsSource = companies;
   //lambda expression to get the Employees of a Company
   ComboBoxEmployees.ItemsSource = employees
}
```

This first initialization **works correctly**.
I really don't know how to proceed. Could you please give me an hint?

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem is in the line before the line you marked. Are you using any indexer, e.g. `employees[0]`?

Comment: Where am I supposed to use it? Before the Binding?

Comment: I did not want to say that you should use it. I just wanted to know if you use something like that. The exception means, that you want to access an index of an array or collection that does not exist

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry for the bad English phrasing. Actually, when debugging, employees list is correct as shown in the Watch Window - it's just the binding that crashes everything. I never use the Gets or ElementAt in these functions I wrote - just binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by inserting

```
ComboBoxEmployees.SelectionChanged-=ComboBoxEmployees_SelectionChanged;
ComboBoxEmployees.ItemsSource = null;
```

before doing any operation or binding. It seems that ComboBoxEmployees was *listening* to the changes with the `ComboBoxEmployees.SelectionChanged` event handler. Also, I was doing mistakes with indexes and pointers.